# Differences between powershell AD Module and the Active Directory Users and Computers MMC?

Tags: active-directory, powershell-remoting

So this is a bit of an esoteric question and I've not found any good links after searching for an hour or so.

What are the communication differences between the Powershell AD Module and the Active Directory MMC tool?

I specifically wanted to know how the tool differs from the Powershell Module when talking to Active Directory?

I assume that Powershell still uses WinRM to speak to the AD system, and that the ADUC is using the direct port access on the various ports (389/etc).  However I don't find a lot of good info on this readily available.

Comment: Both use LDAP or ADSI (wrapper over LDAP) to query AD

Comment: So I will say that I believe the WinRM uses straight LDAP when using the powershell modules.   I have found that you can specify to use the GlobalCatalog, but whats particularly frustrating/odd is that we have a scenario where I can browse the AD with the ADUC tool, but the powershell will not access it.  I'm attempting this now using the Global Catalog ports (3268) to see if I can retrieve data directly from there.

Comment: What is the exact error that Powershell displays? There may be many different reasons, e. g. permissions, or simple serverless binding may contact you to a domain controller which is currently offline

Comment: I'll get this back to you, it looks like there's no response from the DC's that I'm querying with powershell.  This is why I say I think its a firewall related issue.  However it doesn't explain why i can browse their domain.